# Bitmap from media android is returned null all of a sudden

Tags: android, android-bitmap

this used to work and now not anymore. Don't get why.

I want to get reference to a photo from my android phone:

```
Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options ();
options.inSampleSize = 4;

// case 1
final String fname = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), imgDecodableString).getAbsolutePath();
Bitmap fBitmap = decodeFile(new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), imgDecodableString));
// case 2
Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString, options);
```

And while debugging:

```
fname: /data/data/com.test.app/files/storage/emulated/0/Download/A-small-kitten-in-a-Christmas-cap-HD-wallpaper_960x800-1.jpg
imgDecodableString: /storage/emulated/0/Download/A-small-kitten-in-a-Christmas-cap-HD-wallpaper_960x800-1.jpg
```

Bitmap object is always null...
I need a new pair of fresh eyes on this, please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, i deleted the storage permission. Was looking in the wrong place. So the above code works in addition with

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thanks.